# Image not shown when bounding box is used

Tags: graphics, bounding-box

I have a `DIMENSION TOO LARGE` error when I don't put bounding box syntax (`bb=200 570 350 699`). but when I include `bb=200 570 350 699`, pdf is generated but there is no image. Below is my code. Please help me to show the image in my generated pdf.

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\usepackage[top=1.9cm, bottom=2.9cm, left=1.2cm, right=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2.0in,height=2.0in,bb=200 570 350 699]{fig14.eps}
\caption{True Positive Rate (TPR) Vs No. of hops}
\label{figurefig14}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `subfigure` is obsolete and ought not be used. Is your image very large? Does it correctly specify its own bounding box?

Comment: I just edited your question to format your code correctly and correct some of the errors in your grammar and punctuation. Why did you undo all of that?

Comment: sorry...but i thought i did "save edit"

Comment: Exactly how are you compiling? Have you tried viewport instead of bb? Just in case bb is not supported by all engines.

Comment: (i) why you use ˙geometry˙package? if you intent to publish in IEEE journal, thy already have determined page layout according to their rules ... (ii) replace obsolete package `subfigure` with its successor `subfig`; (iii) there is no errors in compilation with and without declared `bb`: different are size and placement of images: without declared `bb` it has correct size and places, without is not (tested with `example-image` from `graphicx` package). Probably it would be better if you trim your image outside LaTeX with some program and than include it with out declaring `bb`.

Comment: i have not tried with viewport.   If i dont include bb i get DIMENSION TOO LARGE error.

Comment: The code compiles fine with some example eps so your eps is the source of the problem. If you get a dimension too large error, then quite probably your image simply *is* to large, perhaps you added to much margin.